# How to make a simualtion in verilog have different results everytime if it has random values?

Tags: random, verilog, system-verilog

I want to generate a different output of the same code every time I run it as it has random values assigned to some variables.  Is there a way to do that, for example seeding using `time` as in C?

Sample code that has the randomization in it:

```
class ABC;

    rand bit [4 : 0] arr []; // dynamic array
    constraint arr_size{

        arr.size() >= 2;
        arr.size() <= 6;

    }


endclass 



module constraint_array_randomization();

ABC test_class;

initial begin 


    test_class = new();
    test_class.randomize();
    $display("The array has the value = %p ", test_class.arr);



end



endmodule
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I this is probably dependent on the tool that is being used. For example xcelium from cadence supports `xrun -seed some_seed`(Questa has `-sv_seed some_seed` I think). I am certain all tools support something similar. Look for simulation tool reference/manual/guide/help it may support random seed for every simulation run.

Not sure if this is possible from inside of simulation.

---

As mentioned in the comments for Questa, `-sv_seed random` should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, concerning Questa `-sv_seed some_seed` i have checked the documentation and it was as follows ` (optional) Seeds the root random number generator for SystemVerilog threads with either a
user-specified integer, or a random number generated by Questa SIM. Also seeds the
shuffle() array ordering operator.` but i still can't figure out how to make Questa chooses that random seed automatically with each run can you help me with that please ?

Comment: `-sv_seed random` [should do the trick](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/399449/a-question-about-randomization-in-verilog)

Comment: Yes, `-sv_seed random ` does exactly what you want. It also prints the chosen seed to the logfile so you can re-run with the same seed again for debugging.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, having an uncontrolled random seeding at simulation creates repeatability issues. In other words, it would be very difficult to debug a failing case if you do not know the seed. But if you insist, then read the following.

You can mimic the 'c' way of randomizing with time. However, there is no good way in verilog to access system time. Therfore, there is no good way to do time based seeding from within the program.

However as always, there is a work-around available. For example, one can use the `$system` call to get the system time (is system-dependent). Then the `srandom` function can be used to set the seed. The following (linux-based) example might work for you (or you can tune it up for your system).

Here the time is provided as unix-time by the `date +'%s'` command. It writes it into a file and then reads from it as 'int' using $fopen/$fscan.

```
module constraint_array_randomization();

ABC test_class;
  int today ; 
initial begin
   // get system time
  $system("date +'%s'  > date_file"); // write date into a file
  fh = $fopen("date_file", "r");
  void'($fscanf(fh, "%d", today)); // cast to void to avoid warnings
  $fclose(fh);
  $system("rm -f date_file");  // remove the file
  
  $display("time = %d", today);

  test_class = new();
  test_class.srandom(today); // seed it
  test_class.randomize();
  $display("The array has the value = %p ", test_class.arr);

end
endmodule
```